# innerHTML reassignment not reflecting on browser

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to replace the HTML in an element on my main page.

This is the JS function I am calling:

```
var insertHtml = function(selector,html) {
    var targetElem = document.querySelector(selector);
    console.log(html);
    targetElem.innerHtml = html;
};
```

The new HTML is displaying on the console, however, no changes are reflected on the browser.

If it helps, these are the calling functions:

```
 dc.loadMenuCategories = function () {
    showloading("#main-content");
    $ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest(categoriesURL, buildAndShowCategoriesHTML);
};

function buildAndShowCategoriesHTML (categories) {
    $ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest(
        categoriesTitleHTML,
        function (categoriesTitleHTML){
            $ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest(
                categoryHTML,
                function (categoryHTML) {
                var categoriesViewHTML =
                    buildCategoriesViewHtml(categories,
                    categoriesTitleHTML,
                    categoryHTML);
                insertHtml("#main-content", categoriesViewHTML);
                },
                false);
    },
        false);
}
```

Does anyone know why these changes are not loading on the browser?

Comment: Does your "#main-content" exist at the moment you replace the html ? Try to log your targetElem too to check it.

Comment: Yes, I previously load content into #main-content as the main page is first loaded. Logging targetElem also works as expected.